# pandas copy value from one column to another if condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
df = 
col1  col2  col3 
1      2     3
1      4     6
3      7     2
```

I want to edit `df`, such that when the value of col1 is smaller than 2 , take the value from `col3`.

So I will get:

```
new_df = 
col1  col2  col3 
3      2     3
6      4     6
3      7     2
```

I tried to use `assign` and `df.loc` but it didn't work.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: you can use `df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'] < 2,df['col3'])`, or `df = df.assign(col1=df['col1'].mask(df['col1'] < 2,df['col3']))` or similar with `np.where`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col3'] if x['col1'] < x['col2'] else x['col1'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 9):

The most eficient way is by using the `loc` operator:

```py
mask = df["col1"] < df["col2"]
df.loc[mask, "col1"] = df.loc[mask, "col3"]
```

Comment: How can the same be achieved when values from multiple columns are to be copied? Something like `["col1", "col2"]` instead of `"col1"` in the second parameter for `loc`?

Comment: You can do multiple `df.loc` statements with different filters

Comment: You mean this? -> `df.loc[mask, ["col1", "col2"]] = df.loc[mask, ["col3", "col4"]]`. It doesn't work for me. But it works when I copy them one by one.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[df["col1"] < 2, "col1"] = df["col3"]
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @anky_91 use `np.where` to update the `'col1'` values:

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] < df['col2'], df['col3'], df['col1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the **apply** function.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda c: c['col3'] if c['col1'] < 2 else c['col1'], axis=1)
```

**Edit**: Sorry, I see from your mock outcome you are referring to col2 rather than an int of 2. Eric Yang's answer will solve your problem.