# assign one column value to another column based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to how we can assign one column value to another column if it has null or 0 value
I have a dataframe like this:

```
id      column1   column2

5263    5400        5400
4354    6567        Null
5656    5456        5456  
5565    6768        3489
4500    3490        Null
```

The Expected Output is

```
id      column1   column2

5263    5400        5400
4354    6567        6567        
5656    5456        5456  
5565    6768        3489
4500    3490        3490
```

that is,
if df['column2'] = Null/0 then it has take df['column1'] value.

Can someone explain, how can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently replace values from a column to another column Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903090/efficiently-replace-values-from-a-column-to-another-column-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39903090/11411793) similar question, you can do the following:

- Using `np.where`:

  ```py
  df['column2'] = np.where((df['column2'] == 'Null') | (df['column2'] == 0), df['column1'], df['column2'])
  ```
- Instead, using only `pandas` and Python:

  ```py
  df['column2'][(df['column2'] == 0) | (df['column2'] == 'Null')] = df['column1']
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Similar question was already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264393/pandas-copy-value-from-one-column-to-another-if-condition-is-met).

"Null" keyword does not exist in python. Empty cells in pandas have np.nan type. So assuming you mean np.nans, one good way to achieve your desired output would be:

Create a boolean mask to select rows with np.nan or 0 value and then copy when mask is True.

```
mask = (df['column2'].isna()) | (df['column2']==0)
df.loc[mask, "column2"] = df.loc[mask, "column1"]
```

Comment: Did you mean ```isna()```? Also abbreviated column names in the second row which will throw an error

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks. Already edited.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion. Not sure whether it is the fastest, but it should work here ;)

````
#we start by creating an empty list 
column2 = []

#for each row in the dataframe 
for i in df.index:
    # if the value col2 is null or 0, then it takes the value of col1
    if df.loc[i, 'column2'] in ['null', 0]:
        column2.append(df.loc[i, 'column1'])
    #else it takes the value of column 2
    else: 
        column2.append(df.loc[i, 'column2'])

#we replace the current column 2 by the new one !
df['column2'] = column2```
````

Answer (score 0):

### Update using only Native Pandas Functionality

```
#Creates boolean array conditionCheck, checking conditions for each row in df
#Where() will only update when conditionCheck == False, so inverted boolean values using "~"

conditionCheck = ~((df['column2'].isna()) | (df['column2']==0))
df["column2"].where(conditionCheck,df["column1"],inplace=True)

print(df)
```

### Code to Generate Sample DataFrame

Changed row 3 of column2 to 0 to test all scenarios

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
        [5263,5400,5400]
        ,[4354,6567,None]
        ,[5656,5456,0]  
        ,[5565,6768,3489]
        ,[4500,3490,None]
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["id","column1","column2"],dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use ffill(). Go through the example.

```
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

items = [1,2,3,4,5]
place = [6,7,8,9,10]
quality = [11,np.nan,12,13,np.nan]


df = pd.DataFrame({"A":items, "B":place, "C":quality})
print(df)
"""
  A   B     C
0  1   6  11.0
1  2   7   NaN
2  3   8  12.0
3  4   9  13.0
4  5  10   NaN

"""

aa = df.ffill(axis=1).astype(int)
print(aa)
"""
   A   B   C
0  1   6  11
1  2   7   7
2  3   8  12
3  4   9  13
4  5  10  10
"""
```